# Numerical Approach to find the Many-Body Ground State Wavefunction of Tight-Binding model

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics

I encounter a problem in finding the many-body ground state wave-function of the tight-binding model in python. The Hamiltonian of tight-binding model is follow:
\begin{equation}
H = -t \sum_{<ij>} c^{\dagger}_{i} c_{j} + \mu \sum_{i}c^{\dagger}_{i}c_{i}
\end{equation}
Suppose I want to solve the 1D Tight-binding model, I can re-write the Hamiltonian in the following matrix form:
\begin{equation}
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mu & -t & 0 & 0 & \dots  & -t \\
    -t & \mu & -t & 0 &\dots  & 0 \\
     0 & -t & \mu & -t &\dots  & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & -t & \mu &\dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
    -t & 0 & 0& \dots & -t  & \mu
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Therefore, I can directly solve the ground-state eigenvalue and the eigenvector. However, the ground state that I solve is the ground state correspond to single particle case. In tight-binding model, we know that the many-body ground state should be the Fermi sea:
\begin{equation}
| \Psi_{GS} \rangle = \prod_{k \leq k_{F}} c^{\dagger}_{k} | 0 \rangle  
\end{equation}
Therefore, my problem is that how can I calculate the many-body ground state wave function once I solve all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the matrix $H$? Besides, how can I relate real-space eigenvectors to momentum space eigenvector like the $|\Psi_{GS} \rangle$?

Comment: Do you have periodic boundary conditions? From your matrix it looks like the answer is maybe no?

Comment: I forgot to impose the period boundary condition for the Hamiltonian. Thanks for reminding.